# What file(s) in core control automatic background updates?

Tags: updates, automatic-updates

I'm trying to understand the background updates feature. What files should I be studying?

Comment: It appears `wp-includes/update.php` and `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php` would be good places to start.